# Jetty Asynchronous handling using AbstractHandler

Tags: java, asynchronous, jetty

I have an embedded jetty server in which I want to handle all the requests asynchronously and process them using a ThreadPoolExecutor but Jetty is calling the same request twice due to which when I start the context again using `request.startAsync()` it throws an IllegalStateException. It works fine if I use `request.setHandled(true)`, but this is not the right approach because this flag should be set after the response is sent back.
I am using ContextHandler class for configuring endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Async Processing with `AsyncContext` will use the `DispatcherType` mechanism per spec.  Be aware of the `request.getDispatcherType()` for each execution through your `ContextHandler` (eg: first is `REQUEST`, next could be `ASYNC`)

Also, you'll need to use a `ContextHandler`, not an `AbstractHandler` to support Async Processing properly.